Using @JsonView on @QueryParam
We're currently using @JsonView to selectively exclude properties in our request and response objects, and it's working great. These properties are not serialized or de-serialized, we are using Swagger annotations as well, and they don’t appear in the generated Swagger schema.
However, it seems that properties mapped with @QueryParam are being ignored in this process (they are still there in the even if they are annotated, in the de-serialized POJO and in the resulting Swagger). I’ve been searching for documentation on this issue but haven’t found any relevant information. Has anyone else encountered this or tried something similar?
Thanks!
